# Using Storage Capacitor with Ionic Storage

Tags: ionic-framework, storage, capacitor

I wish to use both Storage Capacitor and Ionic Storage but i have this error:

```
Duplicate identifier 'Storage'.

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Storage } from '@capacitor/storage';
```

Is there a way to bypass this error ?
I prefer to use both storage

Answer (score 0):

Use imports aliases:

```
import { Storage as IonicStorage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Storage as CapStorage } from '@capacitor/storage';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answser, I have this error now : 'CapStorage' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof CapStorage'?